# One-To-Many relationships with FactoryMuffin in php?

Tags: php, testing, integration-testing, factory-bot, factory

I am trying to use FactoryMuffin, a php factories library similar to FactoryGirl, to generate test data for my integration tests.

In my application, a `Person` can have many `Emails` and many `Tokens`. I'd like to generate a `Person` with five `Emails` and one `Token` in my factory, and write some tests around it.

Currently, I am defining my factories like this:

```
FactoryMuffin::define('Person')->setDefinitions([
    'id'         => Faker::numberBetween(123456789, 987654321),
    'name'      => Faker::name()
]);

FactoryMuffin::define('Email')->setDefinitions([
    'id'         => Faker::numberBetween(123456789, 987654321),
    'address'      => Faker::email(),
    'person_id' => 'factory|Person',

]);

FactoryMuffin::define('Token')->setDefinitions([
    'token'         => Faker::numberBetween(1234567891234, 9876543211234),
    'person_id' => 'factory|Person',

]);
```

My problem is, when I create a `Person`, it does not create any associated `Email`s or `Token`s. When  I create a `Token`, it automatically creates a `Person`, but no associated `Email`s.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the way Factory Muffin works, you don't need to create persons. You can simply create emails and access the person that email created (the other way around). In the below example, we create a Message and then access the User that Message created for us.

Consider this example from their [docs](https://factory-muffin.thephpleague.com/usage/examples/).

```
$message = FactoryMuffin::create('Message');
$this->assertInstanceOf('Message', $message);
$this->assertInstanceOf('User', $message->user);
```

In your case, you could create an `Email` and access the `Person` like below

```
$email = FactoryMuffin::create('Email');
$emailPerson = $email->person;
```

You can even go further and create 100 emails and 50 tokens for the same person like so

```
$person = FactoryMuffin::create('Person');
$emails = FactoryMuffin::seed(100, 'Email', ['person_id' => $person->id]);
$tokens = FactoryMuffin::seed(50, 'Token', ['person_id' => $person->id]);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing, although in reality my database schema is much more complex than this and the code to get all the factories in order remains a bit dirty